# How to keep Controller attributes after switching FXML files?

Tags: java, javafx

There is any way to keep the same attributes of an FXML file controller after switching the FXML file (all FXML files have the same Controller)?

Keeping it simple, I'm making a Simon Says game with a GUI using JavaFX, so as a kind of Back-End I made a 'Game-Engine' which attends all the game inner functions. So, as the game is planned I have multiple screens which depending the settings that were selected in the previous screens, this engine is being configurated. Because the design's comfortabilities I designed the multilple screens in different FXML files using Scene Builder, all of them using the same controller; the matter is that when the FXML file is switched the controller is re-initialized again. The controller uses the engine as an attribute, so this engine is re-initialized again as the controller does. So, I'm looking for a way to keep the engine as the same which was initialize at the first time.

I will put the essential methods of the controller class, the application class does not have any additional line besides the basics.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.SequentialTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author etopo
 */
public class Controller implements Initializable  {

    private GameEngine simon = new GameEngine(); //this line was in the first time in the init method.


     /*
      * Method which initialize another screen/FXML File
      */
    @FXML
    private void inicializaUnJugador(ActionEvent event) {
        simon.setMultijugador(false);
        try {
            switchScene(event, "LevelChooser.fxml");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Archivo mal definido");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void inicializaMultijugador(ActionEvent event){
        simon.setMultijugador(true);
        try{
            switchScene(event, "LevelChooser.fxml");
        } catch (IOException ex){
            System.err.println("Archivo mal definido");
        }
    }

    private void switchScene(ActionEvent event, String url) throws IOException{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(url));
        //loader.setController(this);
        Parent padre = loader.load();
        Scene switcher = new Scene(padre);
        Stage manager = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

        manager.setScene(switcher);
        manager.show();
    }

    @FXML
    private void backToMain(ActionEvent event){
        simon.clear();
        try{
            switchScene(event, "TitlePage.fxml");
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println("Archivo Mal definido");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private void EasyGame(ActionEvent event){
        simon.setDificultad(Dificultad.EASY);
        try{
            switchScene(event, "EasyGame.fxml");
        }catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println("Archivo mal definido");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //Font nes = Font.loadFont(Controller.class.getResource("fonts/kongtext.ttf").toExternalForm(), 20);
        //simon = new GameEngine();
    }
```

So what i do expect is that when a click on a respective button happens, the engine keep the same values on any screen.

Comment: yes, there is no problem using the same controller instance when working with different fxml files. as long as you are clear what you are doing ...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: by default, FXMLLoader creates a new instance of the controller when processing FXML files. but it is possible to manually create the controller and pass it on to the FXMLLoader. this is done with FXMLLoader#setController.

Comment: I've already tried that, it is commented on the code, within the switchScene method. It throws me an IO Exception. Do I have to put it  in another method/class (for example, the application class)?

Comment: there everything looks fine. the error you get is probably due to the fact that it will have a specified controller with the fx:controller attribute in the FXML file. when you manually submit a controller, this attribute should not be specified. also, you can play with setControllerFactory and make a factory to implement singleton.

Comment: @mrmcwolf Bullseye!